# Load 3Ds model in a OpenGL program

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, 3ds

I have a chess board created using OpenGL in VC++.
I have downloaded the chess pieces from elsewhere which has models in 3ds.
I am trying to place this 3ds models on the board.  Help me place the object which can be translated on mouse interaction.

Comment: OpenGL does not have much to do with this. You'll need to obtain or write a mesh loader which reads the mesh info into your own data-structures which you can subsequently render. If you write your own, an easier format like OBJ might be a better initial approach. As for placement on mouse interaction, that is a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL is "merely" a drawing API (though a powerfull one).OpenGL doesn't load 3ds models  but you can of course load 3ds files using a 3ds file loader/parser and feed the extracted data to OpenGL.